# FCM Notification not working in Production mode, works in Development

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am implementing push notification for iOS app using FCM. my Pushnotification API is made in C#.net.

My problem is that when my application was in development mode, notification works, but after made binary (from : diawi.com) for client, the notification did not work anymore, even if I am getting a success message from server.

I followed many links from StackOverflow, but no success.

API Code :

```
            var applicationID ="AAAxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxCUxxxxeA";
            var senderId = "2771xxxxxx16";
            deviceIdAsus = "cEOfJfqoxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxMpGc";
            body = "Pushnotification Iphone TestMessage";
            title = "Test";

            WebRequest tRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send");
            tRequest.Method = "post";
            tRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
            var data = new
            {
                to = deviceIdAsus,
                notification = new
                {
                    body = body,
                    title = title,
                    icon = "myicon",
                    sound = "default",
                },
                data = new
                {
                    body = body,
                    title = title,
                    icon = "myicon",
                    sound = "default",
                },
                priority = "high"
            };

            var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            var json = serializer.Serialize(data);
            Byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
            tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Authorization: key={0}", applicationID));
            tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Sender: id={0}", senderId));
            tRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

            using (Stream dataStream = tRequest.GetRequestStream())
            {
                dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);

                using (WebResponse tResponse = tRequest.GetResponse())
                {
                    using (Stream dataStreamResponse = tResponse.GetResponseStream())
                    {
                        using (StreamReader tReader = new StreamReader(dataStreamResponse))
                        {
                            String sResponseFromServer = tReader.ReadToEnd();
                            response = sResponseFromServer;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Reponse :

```
{
  "Status": "True",
  "Response": "{\"multicast_id\":5525338412933884291,\"success\":1,\"failure\":0,\"canonical_ids\":0,\"results\":[{\"message_id\":\"0:1482845931819882%b367a02ab367a02a\"}]}"
}
```

IOS Code (Objective c) :

```
#define Application_Type @"Production"
        Appdelegate.m
        didFinishLaunchingWithOptions{
        if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) < NSFoundationVersionNumber10_0) {if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) < NSFoundationVersionNumber10_0) {
            UIUserNotificationType allNotificationTypes =
            (UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge);
            UIUserNotificationSettings *settings =
            [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:allNotificationTypes categories:nil];
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
        } else {
  #if defined(__IPHONE_10_0) && __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_10_0
            UNAuthorizationOptions authOptions =
            UNAuthorizationOptionAlert
            | UNAuthorizationOptionSound
            | UNAuthorizationOptionBadge;
            [[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter]10_
             requestAuthorizationWithOptions:authOptions

             ];
             [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter].delegate = self;
            [FIRMessaging messaging].remoteMessageDelegate = self;
    #endif
        }
         [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];        UIUserNotificationType allNotificationTypes =
            (UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge);
            UIUserNotificationSettings *settings =
            [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:allNotificationTypes categories:nil];
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
        } else {
  #if defined(__IPHONE_10_0) && __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= _IPHONE_10_0
            UNAuthorizationOptions authOptions =
            UNAuthorizationOptionAlert
            | UNAuthorizationOptionSound
            | UNAuthorizationOptionBadge;
            [[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter]
             requestAuthorizationWithOptions:authOptions

             ];
             [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter].delegate = self;
            [FIRMessaging messaging].remoteMessageDelegate = self;
    #endif
        }

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
        if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]) {
            UIUserNotificationType allNotificationTypes =
            (UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge);
            UIUserNotificationSettings *settings =
            [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:allNotificationTypes categories:nil];
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
            } else {
            [UIApplication.sharedApplication registerForRemoteNotificationTypes: UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge |
             UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound];
            [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
        }
          [FIRApp configure];
          [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
         addObserver:self selector:@selector(onTokenRefresh)
         name:kFIRInstanceIDTokenRefreshNotification object:nil];
    }
    - (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {
    [[FIRMessaging messaging] disconnect];
   }    
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)settings{
    NSLog(@"Registering device for push notifications..."); // iOS 8
    if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) < NSFoundationVersionNumber10_0) {
        UIUserNotificationType allNotificationTypes =
        (UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge);
        UIUserNotificationSettings *settings =
        [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:allNotificationTypes categories:nil];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
    } else {
      #if defined(__IPHONE_10_0) && __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_10_0
        UNAuthorizationOptions authOptions =
        UNAuthorizationOptionAlert
        | UNAuthorizationOptionSound
        | UNAuthorizationOptionBadge;
        [[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter]
         requestAuthorizationWithOptions:authOptions
        ];
        [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter].delegate = self;
        [FIRMessaging messaging].remoteMessageDelegate = self;
#endif
    }
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
}
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken{
    NSLog(@"deviceToken %@",deviceToken);
    NSString *token = [[deviceToken description] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet: [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"<>"]];
    _strDeviceToke = [token stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
    if (_strDeviceToke) {
        NSLog(@"Device %@",_strDeviceToke);
         #if DEBUG
        [[FIRInstanceID instanceID] setAPNSToken:deviceToken type:FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenTypeSandbox];
   #else
        [[FIRInstanceID instanceID] setAPNSToken:deviceToken type:FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenTypeProd];
   #endif
       NSString *refreshedToken = [[FIRInstanceID instanceID] token];
        NSLog(@"FireBase InstanceID token: %@", refreshedToken);
        if (refreshedToken.length ==0) {
            _strFireBaseToken =refreshedToken;
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setValue:refreshedToken forKey:@"NotificationToken"];
        }
        [self connectToFcm];
     }
   }
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)notification{
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:0];
   if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive) {
        [application setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:0];
     }else if (application.applicationState==UIApplicationStateBackground){
   }
}
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {
}
- (void)connectToFcm {
    [[FIRMessaging messaging] connectWithCompletion:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if (error != nil) {
        } else {
        }
    }];
}
```

and change Code siging ->Provisional profile ->Release ->Distribution certificate

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: did you find answer for this issue ?

Comment: same problem here